# Aviary SDK issue causes app crash in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Hello I am using Aviary SDK in my iOS project. I followed all steps given in this [documentation](https://developers.aviary.com/docs/ios/setup-guide).Now I call below method in viewDidAppear(also try in viewdidload).

```
- (void)displayEditorForImage:(UIImage *)imageToEdit   {
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    [AFPhotoEditorController setAPIKey:kAFAviaryAPIKey secret:kAFAviarySecret];
});

AFPhotoEditorController *editorController = [[AFPhotoEditorController alloc] initWithImage:imageToEdit];
[editorController setDelegate:self];

[self presentViewController:editorController animated:YES completion:nil];     }
```

But when I run the project application is crashed.it will not displaying controller and exception is below

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationBar setAf_backgroundColor:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcb1b950'
```

how can i solve problem.Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure that following the doc correctly?

```
4. Add linker flags

 Update your target's (or project's) build settings to include the following "Other Linker Flags":

-ObjC
-all_load
```

Hope this help you.

Thanks,
Jony